# How to recover encrypted files from sdcard from phone with broken screen?

Tags: external-sd, encryption

So I have a few problems with my Galaxy S9+ phone:

1. About a week ago, my old galaxy s9+ phone's screen started turning black right before the login screen.  I can see the Samsung and verizon splash screens, then mostly nothing but a few white lines at the top.  Since it was about time to upgrade, I went ahead and got a new s20 ultra.
2. The sdcard from it was encrypted and before I realized that, I used it in my new s20 phone, so it now has a few unencrypted files and lots of encrypted files - files and a bunch of other misc stuffs.
3. Using this YT video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RoJt91zKOjE, I am able to boot the phone and mirror the screen to a monitor, but as soon as I login, I see the icon at the top of the screen showing that it is encrypting (or maybe re-encrypting) the sdcard, so I pulled it out as fast as possible.

All of the new files on the sdcard (from the new phone) are expendable.

How do I go about getting all of the "old" files off the sdcard?  Is the encryption process that starts when I boot the phone just encrypting the new files, or re-encrypting everything?

Comment: you can't get encryption key off device so your only chance is put SD Card back in S9+

Comment: Ok.  But what about the encryption process that starts as soon as th phone boots?  Is that double encrypting the already encrypted files? (is that even possible?)

Comment: I have heard FBE adoptable-storage is possible, but I don't find anything about this corner case behavior. usually adoptable-storage is FDE encrypted. In your case it's probably not about adoptable-storage at all, but Samsungs SD Card encryption feature - which does not decide about initial encryption itself. therefore my guess is what you see is resuming encryption (not  double encryption). make a 1:1 copy with `dd` and try